# Android - How To Override the "Back" button so it doesn't stop() my background Activity?

Tags: android, game-development

Android - How To Override the "Back" button so it doesn't stop() my background Activity? For example if my Quiz app run the countdown timer. If user click on back key the count down timer are in running . I want Back key not effect on timer stop or pause

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better solution would be to move the timer to a separate service that runs independently of the Activity you are referring to.
Or you could save the state of the activity once the back button is pressed, and restore onCreate/onStart.